# Trying to make a php button interact with SQL, maybe AJAX?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I set up a VPS today with LAMP, and I'm now looking for a way to easily enter data from the website to the SQL database behind it. What I'm really looking for is this:

A form with five or six drop-down menus, to select different options, and then after you press
'submit', the data is entered into the database. But, I'd like it so that the form is not reset. Will I have to use AJAX for this? I've never used AJAX before, so I'm kind of dreading it.

Comment: Yes you should probably use AJAX to achieve this. You can learn more about AJAX with jQuery here http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use Ajax.

Just set `selected` attributes on the appropriate `<option>` elements when you redisplay the form.